# dropzone.js how to send me mail after upload is completed

Tags: php, dropzone.js

I've added the dropzone.js script to my site and got it working. Now I want to get an email when someone uploads something in this dropzone. I only don't know how to do this in php.

my html:

```
<form action="dropzone/upload.php" class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone"></form>
```

my upload.php

```
<?php
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

$storeFolder = 'uploads';
$digits = '';

$amountOfDigits = 4;
$numbers = range(0,9);
shuffle($numbers);

for($i = 0;$i < $amountOfDigits;$i++)
   $digits .= $numbers[$i];

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds . $storeFolder . $ds;
    $targetFile = $targetPath . time() . '-' . $digits . '-' . $_FILES['file']['name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
}
?>
```

The code above sends the files to the folder I want them with a timestamp so no file will ever override an existing file. Only when this is done I want an email so I know someone uploaded a file. How can this be accomplished.

the mailingscript i want to use:

```
$message = "bunch of html";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers.= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$headers.= "From: examle <info@example.com>\r\n";
$subject = "example";
$to = "me@mydomain.com";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I changed

```
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
```

into:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)
{
    //my mailingcode here
}
```

It worked like I wanted.